# Does the energy eigenvalue have a position dependence?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue

I would like to transform the time independent Schrodinger equation from position to momentum space, but I am stuck on one point: Does the energy eigenvalue act as a unchanged diagonal matrix or does it also undergo a transformation?

I assume since the Hamiltonian has a position dependence, then the energy eigenvalue must also be transformed.

Comment: What did you mean by energy eigenvalue "act" as? If it's wave function, it's fourier transformation. It it's state ket, insert an identity. See: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_and_momentum_space  ). Energy came from time invariance, not directly related to position and momentum duality.

Answer (score 0):

The energy eigenvalue is a number - so many eV’s or whatnot - and not a matrix so it does not change when one goes from the $x$- to the $p$-representation, or when one makes a change of basis.

It is possible that, under a basis transformation, the Hamiltonian matrix no longer takes a diagonal form but the eigenvalues of the transformed Hamiltonian are unchanged.

For instance, $H=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0&1\\ 1&0\end{array}\right)$ has eigenvalues $\pm 1$, and is just a basis change away from the diagonal matrix 
$\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\ 0&-1\end{array}\right)$